# How do i drop a function and a procedure in the same anonymous pl/sql block?

Tags: function, plsql, block, procedure, plsqldeveloper

I have this procedure:

```
 create or replace procedure show_emp
    is
    cursor c is select name,id_funct,date_emp from emp;
...
```

And this function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION raise(cod_ang INTEGER, sum REAL) 
RETURN VARCHAR
  IS
...
```

Everything is correctly implemented.

How do i delete this procedure and this function in an anonymous pl/sql block?
When i try:

```
begin
drop procedure show_emp;
drop function raise;
end;
```

I recive this error:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" when expecting one of the following:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drop` is a `DDL` Statement and you cant use it in  pl/SQL directly.

just do

```
drop procedure show_emp;
drop function raise;
```

or use dynamic SQL to execute ddl statement

```
begin
  execute immediate 'drop procedure show_emp';
  execute immediate 'drop function raise';
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, the execute immediate command is just what i needed.